# Angular MatInput css

Tags: angular, angular-material

I’m using Material on an Angular project.

All the Material components I use work except matInput.

I import the component well and I have the impression that it is well detected as such but its css is not taken into account.

```
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
}
```

_

```
    <form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
        <input type="text" mat-input />
        <input matInput>

        <button mat-flat-button>button</button>
    </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or15k.png)

Mat Button work but Mat Input no.

Comment: It's possible that you have a global css declaration of your own or another library such as bootstrap that is messing with the global styles definitions. Can you confirm it?

Comment: I use Theming Material > @import '~@angular/material/theming' on styles.scss

Comment: But it doesn't have to be that because even if you deactivate Theming Material, the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add any theme in **styles.scss** file. For example:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

After this you should use **matInput** with **<mat-form-field>** tag. For example:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

Quote from [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview):

> **matInput** is a directive that allows native  and 
> elements to work with **<mat-form-field>**.